# How can I change line modification indication colours in the editor gutter in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently in my settings.json file trying to change the colour of modified, deleted, etc. lines in my VS Code. How can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify the following settings in your settings.json file:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // TODO replace "#ff0000" with the hex code of the colours you want
    "editorGutter.background": "#ff0000",
    "editorGutter.addedBackground": "#ff0000",
    "editorGutter.modifiedBackground": "#ff0000",
    "editorGutter.deletedBackground": "#ff0000",
}
```

If you want the settings to only apply to a specific colour theme, do it like so:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Theme Name Goes Here]": {
        "editorGutter.background": "#ff0000",
        ...
    },
}
```

You can also be interested in the `gitDecoration.addedResourceForeground` and other similarly named color customization points.

There are also the following customization points if you are interested:

```json
"minimapGutter.addedBackground": "#ff0000",
"minimapGutter.modifiedBackground": "#ff0000",
"minimapGutter.deletedBackground": "#ff0000"
```